# Request.ClientCertificate.Subject Does not request data all the time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, digital-certificate

I have making test on my app to allow users to login with its digital certificate.
This is not complicated as it requires just one line to actually retrieve data from a magnet card.

This is how I am requesting the data:

```
@{
    string certDados = Request.ClientCertificate.Subject;
    string[] dataArray = certDados.Split(',');
    string data = dataArray.Last();
    string[] numberArr = data.Split(':');
    string number = numberArr.Last();   
}

<td>Utilizar Cert. Digital</td>
<td>@Html.CheckBox("hasDigital")
    @number
</td>
```

The problem is... I can´t get the number all the time. Sometimes the number is there, sometimes not. If I refresh the page a couple of times it appears, and next time I refresh it is not there..

Is there something I could do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution..

```
string certDados = "";
do
{
certDados = Request.ClientCertificate.Subject;
} while (certDados == "");
```

Now it is working... ;O)